# mdDialog: catch the onClose event

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ondestroy, mddialog, oncloselistener

I'm creating a mailbox in angular. And I would need to save the draft message when the popup to send a message closes.

I know there are some alternatives:

```
scope.$on("$destroy", function () { saveMessage() });
```

and:

```
$mdDialog.show(...).finaly(function(){ saveMessage() });
```

But both are insufficient:

- The first is called when the Dialog is already closed. This is due to the requirements unacceptable (there is an iFrame that needs to be open)
- The second is outside the scope of the controller of the mdDialog, and gives the responsibility to the caller of the pop-up, while it should be in the pop-up itself.

So I'm looking for way to call a function BEFORE the pop-up actually closes.
Something like `scope.$on("$mdDialogBeforeClose", function () { saveMessage() });`

Another option would be to hook every close event. Seems ugly, but might be the solution. In that case I would need to listen to the escape-button and clicking outside the pop-up (Altough I might disable that function)...

Any better ideas?

Thx!

**EDIT**:

An addition question: How to catch the escape-keypress event? I tried `<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog" ng-keypress="keyPress($event)">` but it's not even triggered...

Answer (score 10):

Maybe use the `onRemoving` callback - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rrzOLP?editors=1010#0)

From the docs:

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="" ng-app="app">
   <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.open($event)">
      Custom Dialog
    </md-button>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Test">
        Hello!
    </md-dialog>
  </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  this.open = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show(
      {
        templateUrl: "test.html",
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        onRemoving: function (event, removePromise) {
          console.log(123);
        }
    });
  };
})
```

Comment: This has the same issues as the second case I described. I need to be in the controller of the modal. I need to access that scope, and I would like to have the modal itself the responsibility to save the message on every close (we're a team of developers, and there are multiple places where the dialog opens)

Comment: @ThomasStubbe The demos show how to close the dialog with a function in the dialog controller. Do you mean closing the dialog by clicking outside?

Comment: The demo doesn't use a dialog controller at all: `controller: SomeDialogController` should be added to the show-function. Inside that controller there is a function that needs to be executed before close.

Comment: @ThomasStubbe I'm a bit confused :-) Does this work for you? - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rrzOLP?editors=1010#0

Comment: This is what I want, except that the close function should also be triggered when escape is pressed, or clicked outside the dialog. So I want to call that close function in any case when the dialog closes. The two ways to do that I described in my question, but they are either outside the scope of the dialogController (`finally`), or after the HTML is already destroyed (`scope.$on('$destroy')`)

Comment: @ThomasStubbe Would something like this help? - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rrzOLP?editors=1010

Comment: This is indeed a possibility that I haven't considered yet, and would do the job =) But I'm afraid I can't use it though: I have 2 concrete DialogControllers, depending on the type of message, and they extend from another BaseDialogController. Each is over 200 lines, and I call the `show()` from different places, so I cannot just pass the scope to the DialogController, this would bring a lot of issues. Do you know of a way to do this, but with a new scope for the DialogController, instead of passing him?

Comment: I might be able to create a new scope before calling the `show()`: `$rootScope.Scope([providers], [instanceCache]);`

Comment: @ThomasStubbe How about using a service? http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXJKOX?editors=1010

Comment: I need to access functions of that scope in beforeClose() action... There are rest calls (like 4 of them in a row) that need the scope of the mdDialog... 
This works: `var scope = model.$new(true);` and `$mdDialog.show({ ... onRemoving: function() {
                    scope.onDestroy().then(function () {
                    });
                }, ...`
But now I need to find a way to prevent the return of the function until the promise returns

Comment: @ThomasStubbe Sorry I couldn't help. Good luck.

Comment: @ThomasStubbe Why do you need to prevent the function from returning? With `preserveScope: true` I'd expect the functions to still work after closing. Or do you want to prevent closing in certain situations? In this case, re-opening the modal would be an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Dialog return a promise using that you can handle dialog close event

```
var dialogPromise  = $mdDialog.show(
      {
        templateUrl: "test.html",
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        onRemoving: function (event, removePromise) {
          console.log(123);
        }
    });

dialogPromise.then(function(){
   // hide method handler
   // You can write your code here that execute after dialog close
}, function(){

});
```