# $mdDialog, pass object on cancel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

```
this.$mdDialog.show({
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    resolve: {
        product: product
    },
    controller:($mdDialog, product) => {
       close() => {
           $mdDialog.hide({productToUpdate: product}
       }
    },
    templateUrl: 'product-dialog.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
       clickOutsideToClose: true,
    }).then(productToUpdateOrDelete => { // on hide
       cb(productToUpdateOrDelete);
    }, () => { // on clickoutside or escape
       // Need to run my cb() here with the modified product
    });
}
```

I need to pass an object when $mdDialog is closed by escape and clickOutside.

Can't find anything about it in the docs. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to interact with those events, check: [No way to intercept `MdDialog` close events #3893](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3893)

My recomendation would be to do what [@camden_kid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782358/camden-kid) suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765731/mddialog-catch-the-onclose-event#comment66835241_39766803)

1. Create a service
2. Call that service on the `onRemoving` function
3. Save what ever object you need to in that service.
4. In the cancellation of the `$mdDialog.show` promise callback, call the service to obtain the value.

[**Check codepen as example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQGvoE?editors=1010)

Other option would be to use `preserveScope: true` and modify the parent's scope directly and recover the value once the dialog is cancelled.